# Using an adjective after "turn"

Tags: verbs, adjectives, complementation, aspect

Are we allowed to use any adjective after the word "turn"?

For example:

- turn hot
- turn cold
- turn red
- turn white
- turn salty

Comment: As a point of grammar, possibly. Semantically, it depends on what is doing the turning. Weather can turn hot or cold, but it cannot turn left.

Comment: Although *left* is not an adjective in *turn left*.

Comment: @snailplane That's true. Well spotted.

Comment: There's usually a pretty clear-cut distinction between usages like *It's turned cold* (it has ***become*** cold), and *He turned left* (he ***altered course*** in that direction). For non-intuitive reasons, *It's turned hot* is much less likely than *It's turned cold*.

Comment: As a leaner, I would like to say that you may want to have a look on the linking-verb discussions, which are abundant on the internet.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: And there's something in between: "It's turned round." ^_^ (Oh wait, I forgot you don't like jokes.)

Answer (score 1):

In principle you can use any adjective. In practice some expressions are unlikely to be used.

It would be very strange to use this with some absolute adjectives

> ? It turned unique

or adjectives that describe a state that can't be reversed

> ? It turned broken