# Does “to turn oneself something” mean what I want it to mean to a native speaker?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammaticality

Is this sentence correct English?

> You turn yourself listless.

Would you know what it means? Is this how you normally phrase this expression? Is the tense of the verb right? Is that a commonly understood adjective?

I’d basically like to know whether *“to turn oneself **ᴀᴅᴊᴇᴄᴛɪᴠᴇ**”* would mean anything to a native speaker of English, especially with regard to listlessness.

Comment: Well, I'm just asking if saying : " i'm turning myself listless (adj) sometimes" might be grammatically correct somehow, or is this phrase totally wrong?

Comment: Sure! I've already looked up into dictionaries, but they don't seem to mention "turn onself+Adject" directly.  They always seem to add a particle in between like "turn into/in/ to..."   But i'd like to check if  "turn onself + Adjectif" (right behind) correct.   I'd like to mean "Turn" as  "become listless/guilty/happy/sad..." for example.                                                              Thanks

Comment: all right then! i'm gonna use " make yourself+ adjectif" instead, as i'm sure it's working (grammatically speaking)                                                                           Thanks

Comment: Aaah! ok , thanks for the link, i'm going to check into it then, :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using an adjective after "turn"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/110427/using-an-adjective-after-turn)

Answer (score 2):

**He turned himself around**. [His personal situation improved. Phrasal verb: turn around]

**He turned pink or red.** [He looked embarrassed] [Turned=become + adjective]

**He turned the prince into a frog.** [He was a magician]

**The prince turned himself into a frog.** [same as above, grammar-wise]

turn + oneself + adjective is not a grammatical construct in English except in some limited circumstances:

**He turned himself blue when the chemical blew up in his face.**

So, no, it does not make sense to say in English: turn oneself listless.

***What makes sense is to become listless.***

- **He made himself sick thinking about it and became listless.**

Comment: +1 Thank you for helping out this kid. She  was hopelessly lost on EL&U. I'm the guy responsible for closing/migrating  it (according to my logs).  Nevertheless, even here at ELL it  seems that the Q will get closed as dupe.

Comment: @Cascabel Yes,I could see that. Also, she might not know that all caps in a user name is really not so great. I wonder if the Q is a true dupe. :) Sometimes you just have to ring that bell.